# How to select value from Google auto location using Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to automate this to select particular value even the dropdown list id cannot be inspected. Can anyone help me out on this?

Need to select U.S. 22 Imperial from the list

[image: Need to select U.S. 22 Imperial from the list]

Please find the HTML snippet

[image: HTML]

I am unable to proceed more than this. Please help me out!

```
WebElement location = driver.findElement(By.id("selectbox-city-list2"));
location.sendKeys("us");
```

Comment: Can you please add the relevant HTML code snippet and the code you've worked upon ?

Comment: can u send the html snippet

Comment: @Sugan Can you share the url you are using incase it is public?

Comment: Can u try this : Click(xpath=//*[text()="USA"])

Comment: @sai how to select that exact value in the list?

Comment: what ever the text u have given in xpath u can select that

Comment: Once you start typing "US" and the list shows, right-click on the list and choose inspect. You should see the available options. If not, with the list open, search the HTML for one of the available options. Once you find them, they will be HTML and you should be able to locate them as you would any other element on the page. You may have to add a wait to make sure you give the list a chance to populate. If you will post a link to the page, we can help you more.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sendKeys` and send arrow down to select an option. Selecting one by one with the arrow down will highlight the value. You will be able to check the highlighted value using the CSS class of highlighting.

Comment: The problem is you'll have no idea which one you are selecting. The first one down could change based on available options, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  ActionClass

using this you can move your cursor over a specific element based on coordinates and perform a click.

1.So taking the coordinates of that text box.
2.Enter the full value in the text box. ,
3.calculate a very near coordinate to that text box(so that it will be the suggestion) and perform a click.

```
element = xxxxxxx;
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement(element, x_coord, y_coord).click().build.perform();
```